# Word VBA : extracting liked-sentences and placing to end of document

Tags: vba, ms-word

The Word document content is as follows:

```
XXXXX XXXXXX XXXX
XX XXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX
XXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXX (sky)
XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX X
XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX (sky)
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx
XX (sky)
```

I would like to extract sentences ending with (sky) out and have them rightly packed to the end of document, as follows:

```
XXXXX XXXXXX XXXX
XX XXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX X
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxx
XXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXX (sky)
XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX (sky)
XX (sky)
```

How to make use of VBA to attain that?

Comment: Are you asking us to write all that code or are you stuck at something? In case of the latter please [edit] to add that code to your question, if the former I'm afraid this is too broad. We are not a code writing service. The [tour] and [help] explains why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ops. Apologize for that. Meanwhile thanks for editing the layout to be a much more proper one. I am still a newbie to this website and also VBA. :p

Anyway, the problem is solved. :) In case any of you who check out this post may encounter similar situations, my algorithm is as follows (in a rough sketch) :

1. Use Selection.Find to locate the first "(Sky)" ( .Forward = True and .Wrap = wdFindStop )
2. Use Selection.MoveUp and MoveDown to highlight the whole line
3. Use Selection.Cut to cut the whole line to clipboard
4. Run a Selection.Find while loop for the next "(Sky)" ( Using Selection.Find.Execute = True ), and repeat Step 1 to 3 , coupling with Selection.Paste to paste and combine all the sentences with (Sky)
5. Next, create a new paragraph in the end of document using Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory and Selection.TypeParagraph
6. Selection.Paste to paste all the cut sentences
7. Finally, run the code of Selection.Find about replacing Sky with Sky ^p

Thew. Tedious. Hope it helps. Have a nice day all. :)